# how to write raw play queries for a table which is not mapped to an entity

Tags: java, playframework, h2

I am using play framework for the first time and I need to link objects of the same type. In order to do so I have added a self referencing many to many relationship like this:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="journal_predecessor", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="journal_id")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="predecessor_id")})
public List<Journal> journalPredecessor = new ArrayList<Journal>();
```

I obtain the table journal_predecessor which contains the two columns: journal_id and predecessor_id, both being FKs pointing to the primary key of the table journal. 
My question is how can I query this table using raw queries if I am using H2 in-memory database. thanks!

Comment: You should leave the generic playframework tag on your question to increase visibility, and not just the version specific tag. That's what its for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was very easy. I just needed to create an instance of SqlQuery to create a raw query:

> SqlQuery rawQuery = Ebean.createSqlQuery("SELECT journal_id from journal_predecessor where journal_id=" + successorId + " AND predecessor_id=" + predecessorId);

And because i just needed to check weather a row exists or not, I find the size of the set of the results returned by the query:

```
Set<SqlRow> sqlRow = rawQuery.findSet();
int rowExists = sqlRow.size();
```